# String analyser

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity

Use any programming language to display "AWSALILAND" in such a way, so that each letter is in a new line and repeated as many times as its position in the English alphabet. For example letter, (A) should be displayed just once because it is the first letter of the alphabet. Letter D should be displayed 4 times because it is the 4th letter of the alphabet.

So, the output should be this:

```
A
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
A
LLLLLLLLLLLL
IIIIIIIII
LLLLLLLLLLLL
A
NNNNNNNNNNNNNN
DDDD
```

Comment: Are lower-case letters OK?

Comment: IMHO, this challenge would have been more interesting if the text was given as input/argument.

Comment: @Adám IMHO that wouldn't even be a very interesting challenge anyway.

Comment: @PostLeftGhostHunter At least it would omit the unrelated challenge of compressing `AWSALILAND`.

Comment: [somewhat related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/147469/alphabet-staircase), but for string `abcdefghi...xyz`.

Comment: Is a leading linebreak ok?

Comment: is a list of lines an acceptable output format?

Comment: I swear I've seen a challenge like this, but where the string is taken as input. (might've been horizontal rather than vertical, though)

Answer (score 7):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>61</s> 59 bytes

```cs
foreach(var s in"AWSALILAND")WriteLine(new string(s,s-64));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P8/Lb8oNTE5Q6MssUihWCEzT8kxPNjRx9PH0c9FSTO8KLMk1SczL1UjL7VcobikKDMvXaNYp1jXzERT0/r/fwA)

@Kevin Cruijssen Thanks, 2 bytes saved by removing { }

Comment: You can remove the brackets (`{}`)

Comment: Linq version is [63 bytes](https://tio.run/##XY7BCoJAFEX37ysGVzOgA0G0MSUxisIicOEyZHrGA5shZyoj/HYzJIiWBw7nXmUDZRrsb5b0meVP6/ASwi/J1NQ1KkdGW7lGjQ2pPyMjfQ1B1aW17PAC60pHiq1uWs1JO9@6ZpBjVkWsP0bxiHJrSPOFB57vJUWeZJss2S89meNnjLdRrPHBRpe3fhvMpkKIPoRv/m7oxHblEBHwgnR4Z2qURUMOhz/IKz4RIoQOuv4N)

Comment: @aloisdg Thanks, I tried this before also, but it got also more bytes

Comment: Abuse LINQ and `is` (this optimization seems to be almost always applicable to foreach loops) for 57 bytes. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P9fyTE82NHH08fRz0VJzzGvUiPZ1i68KLMk1SczL1UjL7VcobikKDMvXSNZJ1nXzERTM7NYITOvRNP6/38A "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online") (I guess being slightly late is okay?)

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>18</s> 17 bytes

*-1 byte from @Shaggy*

```
`awÑ¢Ó€`u ¬®pIaZc
```

---

```
`awÑ¢Ó€`u ¬®pIaZc   Full program
`awÑ¢Ó€`            Compressed "awasiland"
        u           uppercase
          ¬®        split and map each letter
            p         repeat the letter this many times:
              a         absolute difference of   
               Zc         get charcode
             I            and 64
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9qYXB0//9gYXfDkcKiw5PCgGB1IMKswq5wSWFaY///LVI)

Comment: `Zc uH` -> `IaZc` to save a byte.

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 20 bytes

```
jm*d-Cd64"AWSALILAND
```

Try it online [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jm%2Ad-Cd64%22AWSALILAND&debug=0).

```
jm*d-Cd64"AWSALILAND   
         "AWSALILAND   String literal "AWSALILAND"
 m                     Map each character of the above, as d, using:
     Cd                  Get character code of d
    -  64                Subtract 64
  *d                     Repeat d that many times
j                      Join on newlines, implicit print
```

**19 byte** alternative, which outputs lower case: `jm*dhxGd"awsaliland` - [link](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jm%2AdhxGd%22awsaliland&debug=0)

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 34 bytes

```powershell
"AWSALILAND"|% t*y|%{"$_"*($_-64)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X8kxPNjRx9PH0c9FqUZVoUSrska1WkklXklLQyVe18xEs/b/fwA)

Takes the string `t`oCharArra`y`, then multiplies each letter out the corresponding number of times. Implicit `Write-Output` gives us newlines for free.

Ho-hum.

Answer (score 4):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 112 bytes

```
+++++++[->++>>++>+>++>>+++>+++[<<<]<<]++++>>+>-->++>-->+>-->++>+[[->+>+<<]----[>+<----]>+>[-<.>]++++++++++.<,<<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYvRCYBADEMHir0JShcp96GCIIIfgvPXRA9D24Twulzzfm73elThU1oAocUIcqS7d44QlmEvpjsiUp8BMkYlk7yzS/MWHb@aT6SqHg)

The actual word generation can probably be optimised further.

Answer (score 3):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/) (51 bytes):

```
"AWSALILAND"map(c=>s"$c"*(c-64)mkString)map println
```

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/) (41 bytes):

```
for(c<-"AWSALILAND")println(s"$c"*(c-64))
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8n5@UlZpcouCbmJmnkFpRkpqXUqzgWFCgUP0/Lb9II9lGV8kxPNjRx9PH0c9FSbOgKDOvJCdPo1hJJVlJSyNZ18xEU/N/7X8A)

Comment: This is a code golf question. So you should include your score.

Comment: Very good answer, welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3,41 bytes

```
for i in'AWSALILAND':print(i*(ord(i)-64))
```

## Python 2,40 bytes

```
for i in'AWSALILAND':print i*(ord(i)-64)
```

Comment: [39 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SCFZITNPyTE82NHH08fRz0XJqqAoM69EI78oRSNZU9XYSCtZ8/9/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 17 bytes

```
.•DθîRI§•ʒAyk>×u,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f71HDIpdzOw6vC/I8tBzIPjXJsTLb7vD0Up3//wE)

**Explanation**

```
.•DθîRI§•           # push compressed string "awsaliland"
         ʒ          # filter
          Ayk       # get the index of the current letter in the alphabet
             >      # increment
              ×     # repeat it that many times
               u    # upper-case
                ,   # print
```

We only use filter here to save a byte over other loops due to ac implicit copy of the element on the stack. Filter works here since we print in the loop and don't care about the result of the filter.

Answer (score 3):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax),  <s>16</s>  15 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
êôM▄╬æ♠ª+ç█○==.
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=88934ddcce9106a62b87db093d3d2e&i=)

**Explanation**

```
`'YHu~{YX#`m64-_]*      #Full program, unpacked,
`'YHu~{YX#`             #Compressed "AWSALILAND"
           m            #Use the rest of the program as the block. Print each mapped element with a new-line.
            64          #Put 64 on stack
              -         #Subtract current element by 64
               _        #Get current index
                ]       #Make a 1 element array
                 *      #Duplicate that many times
```

Saved one byte by figuring out that the "*" command works with [arr int] and [int arr].

Comment: Impressive that Stax can compress a string and then compress the entire program again...

Comment: Thanks.  String literal compression works with huffman tree-type stuff, but the output alphabet is 94 printable ascii characters.  The whole-program packing doesn't attempt to use character frequency or order, and (approximately) just converts from base-95 (printable ascii) to base-256 (stax encoding)

Comment: @ETHproductions Which is probably not shorter than directly compressing it once to base 256. Anyway the disadvantage with Stax's packed mode is that it's hard to  put restrictions on the source code.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 17 bytes

```
ＥAWSALILAND×ι⊕⌕αι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3sUBDyTE82NHH08fRz0VJRyEkMze1WCNTR8EzL7koNTc1ryQ1RcMtMy9FI1FHIVMTBKz///@vW5YDAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
 AWSALILAND         Literal string
Ｅ                   Map over characters
                ι   Current character
               α    Uppercase alphabet
              ⌕     Find
             ⊕      Increment
            ι       Current character
           ×        Repeat
                    Implicitly print each entry on its own line
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>64</s> 61 bytes

R's clunky string handling characteristics on full display...

-3 thanks to @Giuseppe, who noticed it's actually shorter to *convert a string from utf8 to int and back again* than using R's native string splitting function...

```r
write(strrep(intToUtf8(s<-utf8ToInt("AWSALILAND"),T),s-64),1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7wosyRVo7ikqCi1QCMzryQkP7QkzUKj2Ea3FEiH5HvmlWgoOYYHO/p4@jj6uShp6oRo6hTrmplo6hhq/v8PAA)

Comment: Before looking at your answer, I would have used `match` against `LETTERS` or `utf8ToInt`, so `strtoi` is a neat trick!

Comment: oh, wait `utf8ToInt` is shorter! [Try it online](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7wosyRVo7ikqCi1QCMzryQkP7QkzUKj2Ea3FEiH5HvmlWgoOYYHO/p4@jj6uShp6oRo6hTrmplo6hhq/v8PAA)

Comment: [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7wosyRVo7ikqCi1QMPHNSTENSg4OtNGt7QkzSIk3zOvREPJMTzY0cfTx9HPRUlT18wkVidTU8dQ8/9/AA "R – Try It Online") using `LETTERS`.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 22 bytes

A more elegant, tacit solution thanks to Adám!

```apl
(↑⎕A∘⍳⍴¨⊢)'AWSALILAND'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v//Ud/UR20TNB61TQSyHB91zHjUu/lR75ZDKx51LdJUdwwPdvTx9HH0c1H//x8A)

Initial solution:

```apl
↑a⍴¨⍨⎕A⍳a←'AWSALILAND'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v//Ud/UR20THrVNTHzUu@XQike9K4Aijo96NycChdUdw4MdfTx9HP1c1P//BwA)

Comment: You shouldn't count `⎕←`. Btw, `↑⎕A∘⍳⍴¨⊢` is the generalised function — at no extra byte cost: [`(↑⎕A∘⍳⍴¨⊢)'AWSALILAND'`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HbxEd9Ux0fdcx41Lv5Ue@WQysedS36n/aobcKj3j6gjKf/o67mQ@uNIeqCg5yBZIiHZ/D/NAV1x/BgRx9PH0c/F3UA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## Java 11, <s>89</s> <s>83</s> <s>82</s> 81 bytes

```java
v->"AWSALILAND".chars().forEach(c->System.out.println(((char)c+"").repeat(c-64)))
```

-1 byte thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY7BCoJAEIbvPsXgaZdwT9FFEoQ6BOZFqEN0mKYttXWV3VWI8NltLS8zzM/PfF@NA0b1/TWRQmvhiJX@BACVdtI8kCTk8wkwtNUdiJ3mNfDYZ2Pgh3XoKoIcNGynIUrC9Fyk2SFL810oqERjGReP1uyRSkZRUrytk41oeyc64yFKM8bmHqdVGHJhZCfR@eZmzTmf4pnR9TflGQvqJ9J4TVY4/@F5uQLyv6MWxHSv1KI3Tl8)

**Explanation:**

```java
v->                      // Method with empty unused parameter and no return-type
  "AWSALILAND".chars().forEach(c->
                         //  Loop over the characters as integer unicode values
    System.out.println(  //   Print with trailing newline:
      ((char)c+"")       //    The current character converted to char and then String
       .repeat(c-64)))   //    repeated the unicode value minus 64 amount of times
```

Comment: [81 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY7BCoJAEIbvPsXgaZdwT9FFEoQ6BOZFqEN0mKYttXWV3VWI8NltLS8zzM/PfF@NA0b1/TWRQmvhiJX@BACVdtI8kCTk8wkwtNUdiJ3mNfDYZ2Pgh3XoKoIcNGynIUrC9Fyk2SFL810oqERjGReP1uyRSkZRUrytk41oeyc64yFKM8bmHqdVGHJhZCfR@eZmzTmf4pnR9TflGQvqJ9J4TVY4/@F5uQLyv6MWxHSv1KI3Tl8)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Ah, didn't realize it was shorter that way. I think tried `chars().mapToObj(c->((char)c)+"").repeat(c-64).forEach(System.out::prinln)` initially somewhere, but obviously it made it longer.. EDIT: Actually, I think I created a tip once about `s.chars().forEach(c->` being shorter than a regular `for(int c:s.getBytes())` once.. If only I would follow my own tips.. ;)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 35 bytes

```perl
say$_ x(31&ord)for AWSALILAND=~/./g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIlXqFCw9hQLb8oRTMtv0jBMTzY0cfTx9HPxbZOX08//f//f/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDQA)

Comment: Why do you add the command line option? would it work if it is removed? What is its purpose?

Comment: @Monolica The option sets the Perl version to 5.10 to make `say` work.

Comment: what is the exact version of Perl you used? What version will run this code exactly without any declaration of what version should be used?

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), <strike>23</strike> 22 bytes

```
(32!r)#'r:"AWSALILAND"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/1/D2EixSFNZvchKyTE82NHH08fRz0Xp/38A)

```
         r:"AWSALILAND"  // set variable r to the string
(32!r)                   // mod 32 each string in r, the operation will use ASCII number
       #'                // for each value in the array, take that amount of the corresponding character in the string
```

Comment: 1 byte shorter: [`64_'r#'r:"AWSALILAND"`](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/9/MJF69SFm9yErJMTzY0cfTx9HPRen/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 31 bytes

```
echo(#&>~_64+a.i.])'AWSALILAND'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I19DWc2uLt7MRDtRL1MvVlPdMTzY0cfTx9HPRf3/fwA)

### Explanation:

```
echo(#&>~_64+a.i.])'AWSALILAND' - print
     #  ~                       - copy (arguments reversed)
      &>                        - each character (can be "0)
               i.               - the index of
                 ]              - the characters in
             a.                 - the alphabet  
         _64+                   - minus 64 (times)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 88 bytes

```
	S ='AWSALILAND'
L	S LEN(1) . X REM . S :F(END)
	&UCASE X @Y
	OUTPUT =DUPL(X,Y)	:(L)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYqxCoAgFABn/Yo3pUIEQZMgJGkQvExSydbmqKH/x5wO7u573uu9h1JIAMX0ETQuqJ1hFKtB63gvoIMMu10rA8iZW2cEJU2adLC1jCclW4o@RVAmeeS5PQWRHAWtZyk/)

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 20 bytes

```
'AWSALILAND'"@@64-Y"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X90xPNjRx9PH0c9FXcnBwcxEN1Lp/38A)

#### Explanation

```
'AWSALILAND'   % Push this string
"              % For each character in this string
  @            %   Push current character
  @            %   Push current character
  64-          %   Implicitly convert to codepoint and subtract 64
  Y"           %   Repeat that many times. Gives a string with the repeated character
               % Implicit end
               % Implicit display
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 59 bytes

```
foreach c"AWSALILAND"[print pad/with c to-integer c - 64 c]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhId@z8tvyg1MTlDIVnJMTzY0cfTx9HPRSm6oCgzr0ShIDFFvzyzBCipUJKvCxRJTU8tAnJ0FcxMFJJj//8HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Z80Golf](https://github.com/lynn/z80golf), 30 bytes

```
00000000: 2114 007e d640 477e ff10 fd23 3e0a ff7e  !..~.@G~...#>..~
00000010: b720 f076 4157 5341 4c49 4c41 4e44       . .vAWSALILAND
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYyxCsJAEER7v2LEftm922TVQjwQRAg2FtZq7tIIdilS5NfPlTjF8GYYZtry8HmXWvmvPYKIgtky@lYZak6lCKP0ISJmfnj0DmuimY7nmYg2B@fV8iD@8bTge7YWKo2hiSrQl@5@5pRVsYhAY7rfUnfp0vVU6xc)

Assembly:

```
ld hl,str			;load address of str
start:
	ld a,(hl)		;get current char
	sub 64 		;get letter num in alphabet
	ld b,a			;store in b
	ld a,(hl)		;get current char
	print_char:
		rst 38h 	;print letter
		djnz print_char	;repeat print loop b times
	inc hl			;increment index of str, to get next char
	ld a,10
	rst 38h 		;print newline
	ld a,(hl)		;get current char
	or a
	jr nz, start		;if current char!=0, keep looping
end:
	halt			;end program (if current char==0)
str:
	db 'AWSALILAND'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZIxT8MwEIVn51ccU4uUKpFgqGg7RAIkpAoGBkZk19fGxbEj@wqh4r@Hc5SqgqVDFNv3fO97lygZ634jCZbLh5dH@IHCt1TIGLFR9nt2nJcFPzI2UGj8LCJp42DmYcbSrtO91VDbPFIQQiyslxqk1gFjBL8FPs4iyUB3mWChzKe1vWbdDgk2hxDQ8buWIRPxoKDsbsuxaJEIA7hDA2wnbVtLhTQ0UblMVpF8wFRUl1q3wTh6T2umECESG93MxWI4H524oPfuCGetWARskecyyrxvQQGZBmMmjNtw6oTBq4BNMjNOYzeGzoE8JBKH3QljgCy7KjsjnBgcflnj8FIQH0BmYs9jOeYwjDUBbP@orlZlDh@I7UBs3C5Dpzl3LS0lXt5xIr8LsoHpv7urVXnNnyuNSSuYVG@v1fppXT3fT3r@Nfpf)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>65</s> 63 bytes

```javascript
i=>[...'AWSALILAND'].map(c=>c.repeat(parseInt(c,36)-9)).join`
`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9mm2lrF62np6fuGB7s6OPp4@jnoh6rl5tYoJFsa5esV5RakJpYolGQWFSc6plXopGsY2ymqWupqamXlZ@Zl8CV8D85P684PydVLyc/XSNNQ1Pz/38A)

**Explanation:**

```javascript
i=>                         // Prints the result of this function
  [...'AWSALILAND'].map(c=> // Loop over the characters
    c.repeat(               // Repeat the current character
      parseInt(c,36)-9)))   // Character to alphabetical position
        .join`
        `                   // Prints a newline after every new char
```

**Edit:** -2 bytes thanks to @BrianH.

Comment: by using an anonymous function you can save 2 bytes: ```i=>[...'AWSALILAND'].map(c=>c.repeat(parseInt(c,36)-9)).join`
` ``` (there's a literal newline in the join argument)

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 43 bytes

```
mapM(putStrLn. \c->c<$['A'..c])"AWSALILAND"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfmfm5iZZxsDpAp8NQpKS4JLinzy9BRiknXtkm1UotUd1fX0kmM1lRzDgx19PH0c/VyU/v//l5yWk5he/F83uaAAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
i|╚┌ž′ø¹‘U{Z⁴W*P
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=aSU3QyV1MjU1QSV1MjUwQyV1MDE3RSV1MjAzMiVGOCVCOSV1MjAxOFUlN0JaJXUyMDc0VypQ,v=0.12)

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 83 bytes

```sql
SELECT REPLICATE(value,ASCII(value)-64)FROM STRING_SPLIT('A-W-S-A-L-I-L-A-N-D','-')
```

`STRING_SPLIT` is supported by [SQL 2016 and later](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql).

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-l`, 21 bytes

```
_X A_-64M"AWSALILAND"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/PkLBMV7XzMRXyTE82NHH08fRz0Xp////ujkA)

```
         "AWSALILAND"  Literal string
        M              to the characters of which we map this function:
   A_                   ASCII value of character
     -64                minus 64 (= 1-based index in alphabet)
_X                      String-repeat character that many times
                       Autoprint, with each item on its own line (-l flag)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>96</s> <s>95</s> <s>77</s> 73 bytes

```c
*s=L" AWSALILAND";main(i){for(;*++s;puts(""))for(i=*s-63;--i;printf(s));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/1@r2NZHScExPNjRx9PH0c9FyTo3MTNPI1OzOi2/SMNaS1u72LqgtKRYQ0lJUxMklGmrVaxrZmytq5tpXVCUmVeSplGsqWld@/8/AA)

-18 bytes thanks to @ErikF

-5 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat

Comment: @ceilingcat So wide characters are good for something! ;-)

Comment: good use of wide chars

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 41 bytes

```
[println(l^(l-'@')) for l∈"AWSALILAND"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P7qgKDOvJCdPIydOI0dX3UFdU1MhLb9IIedRR4eSY3iwo4@nj6Ofi1Ls//8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Swift](https://swift.org), 95 bytes

```
"AWSALILAND".unicodeScalars.forEach{print(String(repeating:String($0),count:Int($0.value)-64))}
```

**[Try it online!](http://jdoodle.com/a/JPk)**

**How?**

```
"AWSALILAND"                             // Starting string
    .unicodeScalars                      // Convert into a list of unicode values
    .forEach {                           // Loop over each number
        print(String(                    // Create a string
            repeating: String($0),       //   that repeats each character
            count: Int($0.value) - 64))  //   the unicode value minus 64 (the offset)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 40 bytes

```
"DNALILASWA"v
 oa~~<v-*88:<
-:0=?^>$:o$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X8nFz9HH08cxONxRqYxLIT@xrs6mTFfLwsLKhkvXysDWPs5OxSpfxfD/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <s>74</s> 68 bytes

```
for(i in s="AWSALILAND")console.log(s[i].repeat(s.charCodeAt(i)-64))
```

- 74->68, -6B for changing `for` loop to `for...in`, saving bytes on loop statement, removed increment, and removing statement to save the character.

Comment: `for(i of"AWSALILAND")console.log(i.repeat(i.charCodeAt()-64))`

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, <s>18</s> 16 bytes

```
`AWSALILAND`ƛøA*
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJqIiwiIiwiYEFXU0FMSUxBTkRgxpvDuEEqIiwiIiwiIl0=)

#### Explained

```
`AWSALILAND`ƛøA*
            ƛ    # mapping lambda
             øA  # string to number in alphabet
               * # times the character
```

`j` flag to print with newlines

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 20 bytes

```
“AWSALILAND”ẋ"O_64ƊY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9RwxzH8GBHH08fRz@XRw1zH@7qVvKPNzM51hX5/z8A)

Comment: I'd suggest `“µɗỊ²ẋ_’ṃØA` to save a byte on the string, but that seems to [throw an error](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5xDW09Of7i769Cmh7u64x81zHy4s/nwDEcgR8k/3szkWFfk//8A) when placed in the program...

Comment: @ETHproductions You need to append a `¤` to that, therefore no bytes are saved. Same luck with compressed strings... :-(

Answer (score 0):

## [MBASIC](https://archive.org/details/BASIC-80_MBASIC_Reference_Manual), 86 bytes

```
 1 S$="AWSALILAND":FOR I=1 TO LEN(S$):P$=MID$(S$,I,1):PRINT STRING$(ASC(P$)-64,P$):NEXT
```

Output:

```
A
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
A
LLLLLLLLLLLL
IIIIIIIII
LLLLLLLLLLLL
A
NNNNNNNNNNNNNN
DDDD
```

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 93 bytes

```php
<?=!array_walk(str_split("AWSALILAND",1),function(&$v){echo str_repeat($v,ord($v)-64)."
";});
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt5WMbGoKLEyvjwxJ1ujuKQovrggJ7NEQ8kxPNjRx9PH0c9FScdQUyetNC@5JDM/T0NNpUyzOjU5I18BpLgotSA1sURDpUwnvygFSGnqmplo6ilxKVnXalr//w8A)

---

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 81 bytes

```php
<?php for(;$i++<10;)echo str_repeat(($s=AWSALILAND)[$i-1],ord($s[$i-1])-64)."
";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go0AhLb9Iw1olU1vbxtDAWjM1OSNfobikKL4otSA1sURDQ6XY1jE82NHH08fRz0UzWiVT1zBWJ78oBSgB4Wjqmplo6ilxKVlz/f8PAA)

Comment: 1) Try `<?=!` - the "not" will negate the `true`; and `false` is printed empty. Or omit the php tag and run with `-r` (that flag is free). 2) 89 byte version: save four bytes with `$i<strlen()...str_repeat($s[$i],ord($s[$i++])...`

Comment: And: as this is Kolgomorov Complexity, you could hardcode the length - saving another four bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/), 83 bytes

```
'AWSALILAND'.runes.forEach((r)=>print(String.fromCharCodes(List.filled(r-64, r))));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0ksKvlflp@ZopCbmJmnoVn9X90xPNjRx9PH0c9FXa@oNC@1WC8tv8g1MTlDQ6NI09auoCgzr0QjuARIpeulFeXnOmckFjnnp6QWa/hkFpfopWXm5KSmaBTpmpnoKBRpAoH1/9r/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 71 bytes

```php
<? for($i=0;$c="AWSALILAND"[$i++];)echo str_repeat($c,ord($c)-64)."\n";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxl4hLb9IQyXT1sBaJdlWyTE82NHH08fRz0UpWiVTWzvWWjM1OSNfobikKL4otSA1sURDJVknvygFSGnqmplo6inF5ClZ////L7@gJDM/r/i/bopCcUZ@UUl8fkFqXnxJYrptfh4A)

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by removing the space after the opening tag and replacing `\n` with a literal newline.

Answer (score 0):

## [Common Lisp](http://www.clisp.org/), 96 bytes

```lisp
(defun x(s)(dotimes(i(length s))(dotimes(j(-(char-int(char s i))96))(princ(char s i)))(terpri)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcoxCoAwDEbhqwSnP0NXwePUWDVSqzQVvH0tLro9Pp5EtbNWTGG@Et0wxnQU3YNBEUNaykrGH25wkNVnp6m8QUbKPPTtObMm@SGjhNywVcVNnR@l4/oA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“þ⁷ʂ:ñ⁵1»O_96×ŒuY
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9qZWxsef//4oCcw77igbfKgjrDseKBtTHCu09fOTbDl8WSdVn//w)**

#### How?

```
“þ⁷ʂ:ñ⁵1»O_96×ŒuY - Main Link: no arguments
“þ⁷ʂ:ñ⁵1»         - compressed list of characters (using words aws, ali & land = awsaliland)
         O        - cast to ordinals = [97,119,115,97,108,105,108,97,110,100]
          _96     - subtract 96 = [1,23,19,1,12,9,12,1,14,4]
              Œu  - upper-case the chain's argument = "AWSALILAND"
             ×    - multiply = ["A","W...W","S...S","A","L...L","I...I","L...L","A","N...N","DDDD"]
                Y - join with newline characters = ["A",'\n',"W...W",'\n',"S...S",'\n',"A",'\n',"L...L",'\n',"I...I",'\n',"L...L",'\n',"A",'\n',"N...N",'\n',"DDDD"]
                  - implicit (smashing) print
```

---

Also @ 17 bytes: `“þ⁷ʂ:ñ⁵1»ØaiⱮ×ŒuY`, and `“þ⁷ʂ:ñ⁵1»O%32×ŒuY`

Answer (score 0):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>90</strike> 83 bytes

```cpp
#include<map>
int main(){for(auto c:"AWSALILAND")c&&puts(&std::string(c-64,c)[0]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/XzkzLzmnNCXVJjexwI4rM69EITcxM09Dszotv0gjsbQkXyHZSskxPNjRx9PH0c9FSTNZTa2gtKRYQ624JMXKqrikKDMvXSNZ18xEJ1kz2iBW07r2/38A)

Thanks to movatica for shaving off 7 bytes!

Comment: Don’t need `c&&`

Comment: @ceilingcat: but then it will crash when it hits the terminating NUL byte.

Comment: `&std::string(c-64,c)[0]` saves three bytes against `std::string(c-64,c).c_str()`

`#include<map>` instead of `#include<string>` saves another 3 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), 100 bytes

```go
import(."fmt"
."strings")
func a(){for _,c:=range"AWSALILAND"{Println(Repeat(string(c),int(c)-64))}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8//X5CYnJ2YnqqQm5iZ9z8ztyC/qERDTyktt0SJS0@puKQoMy@9WEmTK600L1khUUOzOi2/SCFeJ9nKtigxLz1VyTE82NHH08fRz0WpOgCouCQnTyMotSA1sUQDolkjWVMHKAykdM1MNDVra/@DjQJZp6GpUM3FCTSUq/Y/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## QBasic, 57 bytes

```
FOR i=1TO 10
c=ASC("AWSALILAND",i)
?STRING$(c-64,c)
NEXT
```

I'm so glad I was able to avoid using `MID$()` for this challenge!

#### How it works

- Run a `FOR` loop over (1-based) indices of the characters in the string
- Store the ASCII code of the current character as `c`
- Create a string of `c-64` repetitions of character `c` and print it

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 58 bytes

```
while($c=AWSALILAND[$i++])echo str_pad("
",ord($c)-63,$c);
```

prints a leading linebreak. Run with `-nr` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8ec007f9c18fef07281bc0ff0b21d9ff9c440e7f).

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 38 bytes

```python
for c in'AWSALILAND':print ord(c)%64*c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/Py2/SCFZITNP3TE82NHH08fRz0XdqqAoM69EIb8oRSNZU9XMRCv5/38A)

Comment: I like that str_repeat operator. I sometimes wish that PHP had it - but with another character, so we can go on using strings as numbers. And `for <char> in <string>` ... I just love it!

Answer (score 0):

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), 29 bytes

```
00000000: 73e4 0ac7 0eb8 8231 0197 2397 0f12 e0f2  s......1..#.....
00000010: 8401 1461 a02a 3f14 c0e5 0204 00         ...a.*?......
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcwxDsIwEETRnlOMREdhzawNNmk4ix2taaBCOb@xEvjFapt5bWvt5c/tPQZ/LcjRE1jXDHorKBYF6p5hcR52GZzdgE/YUwjn/TkdgqZREgWlm1BpFbErYaVfQePEiX9zVsPlcUhjfAE)

<sup><sup>*I'm sorry...*</sup></sup>

Answer (score 0):

## [F# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 66 bytes

```fs
"AWSALILAND"|>Seq.iter(fun x->printfn"%s"(new string(x,int x-64)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvWTc4vSv3/X8kxPNjRx9PH0c9FqcYuOLVQL7MktUgjrTRPoULXrqAoM68kLU9JtVhJIy@1XKG4BCiQrlGhAxQGypuZaGpq/v8PAA)

Same logic than @pocki_c's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/174187/15214)

I am not used to F# golfing. All inputs are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 39 bytes

```
"AWSALILAND".chars{|x|x.*x.ord-64}
```

Try it offline!

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 162 bytes

```java
static void m(){String n="AWSALILAND";for(int i=0;i<n.length();i++){char c=n.charAt(i);int v=c;for(int z=0;z<v-64;z++)System.out.print(c);System.out.println("");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5Pa4NAEMXvforB02qIplB6MUKFXFpCc7DQQ@lhu2510/0ju6tQxc9uJ1Za0rnMzOO938yZ9nR7rj5nYJI6B4@4F20rBaNeGH2zgzEIACuN46VDDPcttVQBtbUD33BgRimqK5BC84vaKa69W93p0tvuHZHgPFIZ9EZUoKjQpPRW6Pr1bYFFeAvWSlN4Ph1OyK6Q@fcQSFMjoeGWr15FomwKIJiv4CQaf9ig87B4KYvjw7F4OoTZh7FEaA8i32VirxPJde0bZIjNJhpZQy2wXCeXofBEoI7mPme/wQGDw77f3t1mA0bKL@e5SkznkxbvecKi7L8mNQlD/HKepvkb)

Comment: Sure, I will review and edit answer.

Comment: Please check i have update my code.

Comment: Seems to be valid now. Possible [124 bytes](https://tio.run/##VY2xCoMwFEV/JWRKEIOF0sU6BLq0SBeHDqVDGq0@q0lInkIRv90GOnU8l3M5vZpV2tfvTQ8qBHKJKJ0bQCsEa3bZ4qZnJBIwDprMFmoyKjCsQg@mvT8sJ8vIeL5ufwrjy6w8CQWVt0qW51JeTzR/Wc/AIIEiy@EYxNCYFrv4/tm6CEJ3yktkkCQ8rz4Bm1HYCYWLNRwMY5QmmgvfuEYh0@lhz2N73dbtCw).

Comment: [104 Bytes](https://tio.run/##VY2xCsIwFEV/JWRKkAYFcbA4BF2U4tLBQRyesWpqm4TktVBCvz3G0fEcLue2MELRPj5JdRACOWWUznVaAWprVsvohnsmEjALRUarH6QHbViNXpvX9WY5iT3j5Zz@JozHETwJOyovtayOlTwfaPm0nv202gaBdv8GL72HiXEe6ylg0ws7oHC5jJ1hjNKF4sI3rgFkqtisef6Z05y@) using a foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), 22 chars, 44 bytes

```
⊃a/¨⍨⎕A⍳a←'AWSALILAND'
```

test

```
A                      
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS    
A                      
LLLLLLLLLLLL           
IIIIIIIII              
LLLLLLLLLLLL           
A                      
NNNNNNNNNNNNNN         
DDDD
```

Answer (score 0):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 82 bytes

```
/$/NN//#/SSS//"/WWW//!/LLLL/A
"""""""WW
######S
A
!!!
IIIIIIIII
!!!
A
$$$$$$$
DDDD
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcchCsAwDAVQ/2@Rtv6fITAzGDUR0RODirncn6y07LkX7x3jiUw29k5WmhlZ6O6k8JqoKJs76mJQiAjO35qibTimzA8)

Answer (score 0):

### [Turing Machine But Way Worse](https://github.com/MilkyWay90/Turing-Machine-But-Way-Worse) - 4349 bytes

```
0 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 1 1 1 2 0 0
0 2 0 1 3 0 0
0 3 0 1 4 0 0
0 4 0 1 5 0 0
0 5 0 1 6 0 0
0 6 0 1 7 0 0
0 7 1 0 8 1 0
0 8 1 1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 1 0 0
1 1 1 0 9 0 0
0 9 0 0 10 0 0
0 10 1 0 11 0 0
0 11 0 0 12 0 0
0 12 0 0 2 0 0
1 2 0 0 13 1 0
0 13 0 1 14 0 0
0 14 1 0 15 0 0
0 15 0 1 3 0 0
1 3 1 1 16 0 0
0 16 0 1 17 0 0
0 17 1 0 18 0 0
0 18 0 1 4 0 0
1 4 1 1 5 0 0
1 5 0 0 6 0 0
1 6 1 1 19 0 0
0 19 0 1 20 0 0
0 20 1 1 7 0 0
1 7 1 1 21 0 0
0 21 1 0 8 1 0
1 8 1 0 9 1 0
1 9 1 0 22 1 0
0 22 0 0 10 1 0
1 10 1 1 23 1 0
0 23 0 0 11 1 0
1 11 1 1 24 1 0
0 24 0 0 12 1 0
1 12 1 1 25 1 0
0 25 0 0 13 1 0
1 13 1 1 26 1 0
0 26 0 0 14 1 0
1 14 1 1 27 1 0
0 27 0 0 15 1 0
1 15 1 1 28 1 0
0 28 0 0 16 1 0
1 16 1 1 29 1 0
0 29 0 0 17 1 0
1 17 1 1 30 1 0
0 30 0 0 18 1 0
1 18 1 1 31 1 0
0 31 0 0 19 1 0
1 19 1 1 32 1 0
0 32 1 1 20 0 0
1 20 0 1 21 0 0
1 21 1 1 22 0 0
1 22 0 0 23 0 0
1 23 1 0 33 0 0
0 33 0 0 24 0 0
1 24 1 0 25 0 0
1 25 0 0 34 0 0
0 34 0 0 26 0 0
1 26 0 0 35 1 0
0 35 0 1 36 0 0
0 36 1 0 37 0 0
0 37 0 1 27 0 0
1 27 1 1 38 0 0
0 38 0 1 39 0 0
0 39 1 0 40 0 0
0 40 0 1 28 0 0
1 28 1 1 29 0 0
1 29 0 1 41 0 0
0 41 0 1 30 0 0
1 30 1 1 42 0 0
0 42 1 0 31 1 0
1 31 1 0 43 1 0
0 43 0 0 44 1 0
0 44 0 0 32 1 0
1 32 1 1 45 1 0
0 45 0 0 33 1 0
1 33 1 1 46 1 0
0 46 0 0 34 1 0
1 34 1 1 47 1 0
0 47 0 0 35 1 0
1 35 1 1 48 1 0
0 48 0 0 36 1 0
1 36 1 1 49 1 0
0 49 0 0 37 1 0
1 37 1 1 50 1 0
0 50 0 0 38 1 0
1 38 1 1 51 1 0
0 51 0 0 39 1 0
1 39 1 1 52 1 0
0 52 1 1 53 0 0
0 53 0 1 40 0 0
1 40 1 1 41 0 0
1 41 0 0 42 0 0
1 42 1 0 54 0 0
0 54 0 0 43 0 0
1 43 1 0 44 0 0
1 44 0 0 55 0 0
0 55 0 0 45 0 0
1 45 0 0 56 1 0
0 56 0 1 57 0 0
0 57 1 0 58 0 0
0 58 0 1 46 0 0
1 46 1 1 59 0 0
0 59 0 1 60 0 0
0 60 0 1 47 0 0
1 47 0 0 61 0 0
0 61 0 1 62 0 0
0 62 0 1 63 0 0
0 63 0 1 48 0 0
1 48 0 1 64 0 0
0 64 1 0 65 1 0
0 65 1 1 49 0 0
1 49 0 0 50 0 0
1 50 1 0 66 0 0
0 66 0 0 67 0 0
0 67 1 0 68 0 0
0 68 0 0 69 0 0
0 69 0 0 51 0 0
1 51 0 0 70 1 0
0 70 0 1 71 0 0
0 71 1 0 72 0 0
0 72 0 1 52 0 0
1 52 1 1 73 0 0
0 73 0 1 74 0 0
0 74 0 1 53 0 0
1 53 1 1 75 0 0
0 75 1 1 54 0 0
1 54 0 0 55 1 0
1 55 1 0 56 1 0
1 56 1 0 76 1 0
0 76 0 1 57 1 0
1 57 1 0 77 1 0
0 77 0 1 58 1 0
1 58 1 0 78 1 0
0 78 0 1 59 1 0
1 59 1 0 79 1 0
0 79 0 1 60 1 0
1 60 1 0 80 1 0
0 80 0 1 61 1 0
1 61 1 1 62 0 0
1 62 0 1 81 0 0
0 81 1 0 82 0 0
0 82 0 0 63 0 0
1 63 1 0 83 0 0
0 83 0 0 84 0 0
0 84 0 0 64 0 0
1 64 0 0 85 1 0
0 85 0 1 86 0 0
0 86 1 0 87 0 0
0 87 0 1 65 0 0
1 65 1 1 88 0 0
0 88 0 1 89 0 0
0 89 0 1 66 0 0
1 66 1 1 90 0 0
0 90 0 1 67 0 0
1 67 0 1 91 0 0
0 91 1 0 92 1 0
0 92 0 0 93 1 0
0 93 0 0 68 1 0
1 68 1 0 94 1 0
0 94 0 1 69 1 0
1 69 1 0 95 1 0
0 95 0 1 70 1 0
1 70 1 0 96 1 0
0 96 0 1 71 1 0
1 71 1 1 97 0 0
0 97 0 1 98 0 0
0 98 1 1 72 0 0
1 72 0 0 73 0 0
1 73 1 0 99 0 0
0 99 0 0 74 0 0
1 74 1 0 100 0 0
0 100 0 0 101 0 0
0 101 0 0 75 0 0
1 75 0 0 102 1 0
0 102 0 1 103 0 0
0 103 1 0 104 0 0
0 104 0 1 76 0 0
1 76 1 1 105 0 0
0 105 0 1 106 0 0
0 106 0 1 77 0 0
1 77 1 1 107 0 0
0 107 1 1 78 0 0
1 78 0 0 79 1 0
1 79 1 0 80 1 0
1 80 1 0 108 1 0
0 108 0 1 81 1 0
1 81 1 0 109 1 0
0 109 0 1 82 1 0
1 82 1 0 110 1 0
0 110 0 1 83 1 0
1 83 1 0 111 1 0
0 111 0 1 84 1 0
1 84 1 0 112 1 0
0 112 0 1 85 1 0
1 85 1 1 86 0 0
1 86 0 1 113 0 0
0 113 1 0 114 0 0
0 114 0 0 87 0 0
1 87 1 0 115 0 0
0 115 0 0 116 0 0
0 116 0 0 88 0 0
1 88 0 0 117 1 0
0 117 0 1 118 0 0
0 118 1 0 119 0 0
0 119 0 1 89 0 0
1 89 1 1 120 0 0
0 120 0 1 121 0 0
0 121 0 1 90 0 0
1 90 0 0 122 0 0
0 122 0 1 123 0 0
0 123 0 1 124 0 0
0 124 0 1 91 0 0
1 91 0 1 125 0 0
0 125 1 0 126 1 0
0 126 1 1 92 0 0
1 92 0 0 93 0 0
1 93 1 0 127 0 0
0 127 0 0 128 0 0
0 128 1 0 129 0 0
0 129 0 0 130 0 0
0 130 0 0 94 0 0
1 94 0 0 131 1 0
0 131 0 1 132 0 0
0 132 1 1 133 0 0
0 133 0 1 134 0 0
0 134 0 1 95 0 0
1 95 1 1 135 0 0
0 135 1 0 96 1 0
1 96 1 0 136 1 0
0 136 0 1 97 1 0
1 97 1 0 137 1 0
0 137 0 1 98 1 0
1 98 1 0 138 1 0
0 138 0 1 99 1 0
1 99 1 0 139 1 0
0 139 0 1 100 1 0
1 100 1 0 140 1 0
0 140 0 1 101 1 0
1 101 1 0 141 1 0
0 141 0 1 102 1 0
1 102 1 0 142 1 0
0 142 0 1 103 0 0
1 103 1 1 104 0 0
1 104 0 0 105 0 0
1 105 1 0 143 0 0
0 143 0 0 144 0 0
0 144 0 0 106 0 0
1 106 0 0 145 1 0
0 145 0 1 146 0 0
0 146 1 0 147 0 0
0 147 0 1 107 0 0
1 107 1 1 148 0 0
0 148 0 1 149 0 0
0 149 0 1 108 0 0
1 108 0 0 150 0 0
0 150 0 1 151 0 0
0 151 0 1 152 0 0
0 152 1 1 109 0 0
1 109 0 0 110 1 0
1 110 1 0 153 1 0
0 153 0 0 154 1 0
0 154 0 1 155 1 1
```

Made with the help of ASCII_only's program generator

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 88 bytes

```
lmap x [split AWSALILAND ""] {set s ""
time {set s $s$x} [expr [scan $x %c]-64]
puts $s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f8/JzexQKFCIbq4ICezRMExPNjRx9PH0c9FQUkpVqG6OLVEoRjI5CrJzE2FcVWKVSpqFaJTKwqKgPqSE/MUVCoUVJNjdc1MYrkKSktAKmr//wcA)

Comment: Also 88 bytes: https://tio.run/##K0nO@f8/JzexQKFCIbq4ICezRMExPNjRx9PH0c9FQUkpVqG6JDM3VaE6saAgNS9FoVhBpaJWITq1oqAIqD45MQ/IV1BNjtU1M4nlKigtAcoXc5XmFaeWKBTX/v8PAA

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 37 bytes

```perl6
say .chr x$_-64 for "AWSALILAND".ords
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVJBLzmjSKFCJV7XzEQhLb9IQckxPNjRx9PH0c9FSS@/KKX4/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## VBA (Excel), 70 bytes

using Immediate window

```
a="AWSALILAND":For x=1To Len(a):b=Mid(a,x,1):?String(Asc(b)-64,b):Next
```

Answer (score 0):

## 8088 machine code, IBM PC DOS, 40 bytes

**Listing:**

```
B4 02       MOV  AH, 2          ; DOS API display char function
B1 0A       MOV  CL, 10         ; CL length of string 
BE 011E     MOV  SI, OFFSET S   ; point SI to AWSALILAND string  
    LOOP_CHAR:   
AC          LODSB               ; load next byte into AL 
8A D0       MOV  DL, AL         ; put in DL for display 
2C 40       SUB  AL, 'A'-1      ; convert ASCII char to 1-based counter 
8A D8       MOV  BL, AL         ; move to BL for repeat loop 
    LOOP_REP: 
CD 21       INT  21H            ; display char in DL 
4B          DEC  BX             ; decrement repeat counter 
75 FB       JNZ  LOOP_REP       ; repeat char loop 
B2 0D       MOV  DL, 0DH        ; display CR 
CD 21       INT  21H 
B2 0A       MOV  DL, 0AH        ; display LF 
CD 21       INT  21H 
E2 EA       LOOP LOOP_CHAR      ; next char loop 
C3          RET                 ; return to DOS 

S   DB      'AWSALILAND'        ; define static string in memory
```

Actually turned out to be longer than I thought.  Of course, it doesn't help that it costs 8 bytes to display a newline using the DOS console API.

**Output**

[image]

Download and test [AWA.COM](https://stage.stonedrop.com/ppcg/AWA.COM).

Answer (score 0):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 192 bytes

```
{i}ddsic{{d}}{i}cs{d}dddccc{cc}{{d}}{i}cdsii{c}ccccccccc{{d}}{i}cddsic{{d}}{i}cdsddddd{c}cc{{d}}{i}cdds{i}dccccccccc{{d}}{i}cdsddddd{c}cc{{d}}{i}cddsic{{d}}{i}cdsddd{c}cccc{{d}}{i}cddsiiiicccc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY1BDoBACANf5KNMq5EzR8LbETa66xrtCcqUclu5ix5LhImTKjCjey7QHEgCMMC7nYwYHLfGYUpTWWrkE6maj@wP/X54FU9IqryIEw)

Frankly, I'm just stoked it's below 200 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ahead](https://github.com/ajc2/ahead), 34 bytes

Contains trailing newline.

```
"AWSALILAND"u$l<
~dW:k-A':\N\0<~n@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xITUz5/1/JMTzY0cfTx9HPRalUJceGqy4l3Cpb11HdKsYvxsCmLs/h/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 56 bytes

```
K`AWSALILAND
L`.
W
23*W
S
19*S
L
22*L
I
9*I
D
4*D
N
14*N
```

**Explanation:**

```
K`AWSALIAND
```

Sets the working string to AWSALIAND

```
L`.
```

Puts each character onto a new line. `L` is a list, and each item is found by the regex `/./`.

```
character
n*character
```

Replace all occurences of character with n lots of the character.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcEhDoAwDEBR/49SQbIxM7lkZqGZqagdAoFBEO5f3nuv737OFHGs5tZ0aJsdXRtO3sUxUhVDyVmUQZVBp0hnkorMiB8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Poetic](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/index.html), 470 bytes

```
any days i wish i could&i say i could,i can not
still at the age where,a lot of times,i can not raise my own money
guess i got myself overly exhausted,or spent
no pun is meant
i was a child of ten,a child of ten
a thing i know:i saved a buck a month
m-one-y,m-one-y,m-ones-y
still,i had a dream,i had a vision
oh my god,what a dream
i had a vision i was rich
at first im like:o,i have a payoff,o
however,truly i am not especially pleased
indeed,o,i see i am scared of it
```

[Try it online!](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/tio/index.html?VVBLlsMgDNtzCq9mRS/Q27jBCX4FOw@TZDj9jJPO53WlJ5BtSSgDEg4DhoMtO0y6lfTBYDh@WXREAdEerHMpgB16JsCF4MjUKCIU7aAzdK5k/3poyEZQB@ghUFVohGUjO@8t/l2HUZlBd2plAH1m3KxTitrAVpIeRGHdBNigEjp3m2iAMGUu6TpIEt9pQDfHsviJp@hxP6PslHzosU1PB7fRc6g3d3Mb8Q3tNl4RPULGcyY1wvrHdjZWCZrPSIumeGTv4kcV3lXw8tp4ysFFMzfrwBUKP@mu18rdO4QVh85z1JD1IC8i9raVs3usV4XkTUyMxd/WQmiUAkuisyVfYkQvqU3Y6OqA@9fXA9M3)

I don't especially like the fact that I have to hardcode `AWSALILAND` (mostly because I don't know what that *means*). But at least this works.

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 19 bytes

```
mSRo-64c"AWSALILAND
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/Pzc4KF/XzCRZyTE82NHH08fRz@X/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 284 bytes

```
{iiiiii}iiiiic{ddddd}dddddc{{i}dd}ddd{cc}ccc{{d}ii}iiic{{i}ddd}iii{c}ccccccccc{{d}iii}dddc{iiiii}iiiiic{ddddd}dddddc{iiiiii}iiiiii{c}cc{dddddd}ddddddc{iiiiii}iiiccccccccc{dddddd}dddc{iiiiii}iiiiii{c}cc{dddddd}ddddddc{iiiii}iiiiic{ddddd}dddddc{{i}ddd}dd{c}cccc{{d}iii}iic{iiiiii}ddcccc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY87DoAwDENPxKGQAyIzo5Wzh@aDCgMSHiK5fnVT2VbZ9TwWd2rKcoISspwg1coQMGAciBXaWVhlZqUiMgK/i59v1v3KG3gRs3sivxu@vxWuN7@XDrB7BzbkfgE)

Answer (score 0):

## [CSASM v2.2.1.2](https://github.com/absoluteAquarian/CSASM/releases/tag/v2.2.1.2), 162 bytes

```
func main:
lda 0
sta $1
lda "AWSALILAND"
.lbl a
push $a
conv ~arr:char
ldelem $1
dup
conv i32
push 64
sub
pop $2
conv str
push $2
mul
print.n
inc $1
push $1
push 10
sub
brtrue a
ret
end
```

**Commented and ungolfed:**

```
func main:
    ; Initialize $1 to zero and $a to the string "AWSALILAND"
    lda 0
    sta $1
    lda "AWSALILAND"
    
    .lbl loop
        ; Get the iteration char in the string
        push $a
        conv ~arr:char
        ldelem $1

        ; Duplicate it.  The first will be used as the string to print and the
        ;   second will be used for the string repetitions with "mul"
        dup

        ; Get the index in the alphabet (1..26) and put it in $2
        conv i32
        push 64
        sub
        pop $2

        ; Convert the character to a string, then perform the built-in string
        ;   repetitions with "mul"
        conv str
        push $2
        mul

        ; Print it with a newline appended
        print.n

        ; Truthy is non-zero, so the loop ends when ($1 + 1) - 10 == 0
        inc $1
        push $1
        push 10
        sub
        brtrue loop
    ret
end
```